# jenkins installation on wsl ubuntu issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

```
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install jenkins
```

these commands are not working fine when I'm running this im getting:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package jenkins is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'jenkins' has no installation candidate
```

How can i install jenkins in wsl ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps.

First install certificates for WSL environment.

`sudo apt install ca-certificates`

Then Install Jenkins.

```bash
curl -fsSL https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo tee \
  /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc > /dev/null

echo deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc] \
https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ | sudo tee \
 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list > /dev/null

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

Note: If you have docker running it's better to start Jenkins as a Docker container.